# How can I apply a name to an environment?

Tags: r

The global environment seems to have the name `R_GlobalEnv`

```
environment()
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

I'd like to attach a name to a new environment `e` so that if I name it *myEnv*, it reads

```
e
# <environment: myEnv>
```

But it  doesn't seem like this is possible.  There are no arguments in `new.env` that allow this, and `attr<-` doesn't seem to work.

```
e <- new.env()
attr(e, "names") <- "myEnv"
# Error in attr(e, "names") <- "myEnv" : names() applied to a non-vector
```

Is it possible to name the environment, maintain the byte code, and have it print as shown above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `?environment`:

> System environments, such as the base, global and empty 
>   environments, have names as do the package and namespace  environments
>   and those generated by ‘attach()’.  Other  environments can be named
>   by giving a ‘"name"’ attribute

Therefore:

```
attr(e, "name") <- "yip"
e
#<environment: 0x00000000080974f8>
#attr(,"name")
#[1] "yip"
environmentName(e)
#[1] "yip"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can give it a class and write an S3 `print` method

```
> e <- new.env()
> class(e) <- "myClass"
> print.myClass <- function(x, ...) cat("<environment: myEnv>\n")
> e
<environment: myEnv>
```

---

Combining @thelatemail's answer with mine... you could do this

```
e <- new.env()
print.myClass <- function(x, ...) cat("<environment: ", environmentName(x), ">\n", sep="")
class(e) <- "myClass"
e
#<environment: >
attr(e, "name") <- "myEnv"
e
#<environment: myEnv>
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the code used to print environments (`./src/main/printutils.c` as of r66641), you can't get it to print as:

```
> e
<environment: myEnv>
```

Here's the relevant section of `printutils.c`:

```
attribute_hidden
const char *EncodeEnvironment(SEXP x)
{
    const void *vmax = vmaxget();
    static char ch[1000];
    if (x == R_GlobalEnv)
    sprintf(ch, "<environment: R_GlobalEnv>");
    else if (x == R_BaseEnv)
    sprintf(ch, "<environment: base>");
    else if (x == R_EmptyEnv)
    sprintf(ch, "<environment: R_EmptyEnv>");
    else if (R_IsPackageEnv(x))
    snprintf(ch, 1000, "<environment: %s>",
        translateChar(STRING_ELT(R_PackageEnvName(x), 0)));
    else if (R_IsNamespaceEnv(x))
    snprintf(ch, 1000, "<environment: namespace:%s>",
        translateChar(STRING_ELT(R_NamespaceEnvSpec(x), 0)));
    else snprintf(ch, 1000, "<environment: %p>", (void *)x);

    vmaxset(vmax);
    return ch;
}
```