# R: Store similar functions in named environments

Tags: r, namespaces

I find convenient to group similar functions in environments.

```
myenv <-  new.env()
f <- function() print(1)
assign("f", f, myenv)
rm(f) # use before attach to avoid  "object is masked" message
attach(myenv)
rm(myenv)
```

In this way I can list the related functions together with:

```
ls("myenv")
# [1] "f"   # and any other possible function defined in myenv
```

Anyway, when I print the function:

```
f
# function() print(1)
# <environment: 0x000000001df15d80>
```

I get only a reference to the environment hash, while it would be nice to get a reference to the actual name like for packages:

```
sd
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), 
    na.rm = na.rm))
<bytecode: 0x000000001c01d8a8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Is it possible or am I compelled to create a package?

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925169/how-can-i-apply-a-name-to-an-environment/25925283

Comment: @thelatemail: Unless you think mine is a duplicate, you might post an answer, which I can accept.

Comment: @thelatemail: Upon verification I saw that it does not work for printing the functions, but only for the environments.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of code, so it is convenient to store it in separate functions.

```
print.store.f <- function(x, useSource = TRUE, ...) {
    class(x) <- NULL
    print.function(x, useSource = TRUE, ...)
    cat("<environment: myEnv>\n")
}
storeInEnv <- function(fun, env){
    if( ! env  %in% search()) attach(new.env(), name=env)        
    assign(fun, get(fun, parent.frame()), as.environment(env))
    eval(parse(t=sprintf("class(%s) <- 'store.f'", fun)), as.environment(env))
    rm(list=fun, pos=parent.frame())
}
```

Now, after creating a function:

```
f <- function() print(1)
```

it is possible to store it in an environment, which is created if necessary,

```
storeInEnv("f", "myenv")
```

And now:

```
f
# function() print(1)
# <environment: myEnv>
```

Note that the function has been removed from the global environment and exists only in `myenv`:

```
getAnywhere(f)
# A single object matching 'f' was found
# It was found in the following places
#   myenv
# with value
#  
# function() print(1)
# <environment: myEnv>
```